# How to tie "Primary" and "Secondary" monitor spaces?

Tags: macos, spaces

I want to have 9 set of spaces, each one spanning 2 monitors. In other words, when I switch to space 1, both of my monitors update their current space, as in the following diagram

[image]

I saw "Displays use different spaces" setting, but this doesn't quite do what I want

Is there some setting or a utility I can use for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. "Displays use different spaces" specifically 'un-links' the monitors, allowing each to contain a different space. Each is then independently called.

Comment: updated with a diagram to clarify

Comment: That simply looks like you need to disable "Displays have different spaces", that will make them move as coherent pairs. Additionally disabling 'auto rearrange based on recent' will make the numbering stick.

Comment: if I disable that setting then my secondary is pinned to a single space, while the primary switches between spaces

Comment: This is the way I've had my Spaces set since they were invented. As far as I'm aware there's no way to even achieve the behaviour you state. Have you rebooted since setting this up?

Comment: I recorded this gif [intentionally blurred] to demonstrate cycling through my 7 Spaces, in matched pairs. If this isn't what you meant, please let me know. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JidcN.gif

Comment: I still don’t know what either of you are talking about. Maybe two more pictures that are less abstract is needed. What do you want on two screens initially, what are you going to change or type and then what do you want to see on the two screens after that operation is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have intentionally blurred the window contents; no need to clean your glasses ;)*

Disable "Displays have different spaces", that will make them move as coherent pairs. Additionally disabling 'auto rearrange based on recent' will make the numbering stick.

So - this is 2 monitors, 7 spaces. Each 'Space' covers the pair of screens & their contents. Changing Space changes both monitors simultaneously.
The 'reappearing window' top right is Activity Monitor, which is set to be on all Spaces. Everything else lives on its own Space & only appears when I switch to that Space.
The gif is a 'live' movie of me using the keyboard to call each Space in sequence, then back to the first [then the gif cycles & you see the movie title again]

[image]